# How to override/customize OpenAPI Spec Version in my Swagger UI?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, swagger-ui, openapi, openapi-generator

I've defined a Swagger UI for my API using a yaml file, with the openapi 3.0.0 specification. That specification requires defining a version, which shows up at the top of the Swagger Page. But I want my Swagger-UI to use my Gradle file's version instead, so I don't have to worry about changing both versions all the time. But nothing seems to work.

Is there not a way to overwrite the specification-file's version?

Here's what I have:

build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
version = "0.0.3" // <= I want this on my Swagger Page
group = "com.my.api"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.6.15")
}
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("kotlin")
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/src/main/resources/static/my-api-spec.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/generated")
    modelPackage.set("com.my.api.web.model")
    globalProperties.set(mapOf(
        "apis" to "false",
        "apiDocs" to "false",
        "apiTests" to "false",
        "models" to "",
        "modelTests" to "false",
        "modelDocs" to "false",
        "invoker" to "false"
    ))
    configOptions.set(mapOf(
        "serializationLibrary" to "jackson",
        "sourceFolder" to ""
    ))
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDir("$buildDir/generated")
    }
}
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    dependsOn(tasks.openApiGenerate)
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
```

src/main/resources/application.yml

```yaml
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    enabled: true
    url: /my-api-spec.yaml
    path: /swagger-ui.html
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
    path: /api-docs
```

src/main/resources/static/my-api-spec.yaml

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: My Little API
  description: "API for doing things"
  version: "placeholder" # But this shows up no matter what

servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080/
    description: "Local"

paths:
  /me:
    get:
      summary: "Get Current User Details"
      description: "Returns basic details about the current Authenticated User"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: "The Current Authenticated User's Details"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/BasicUserInfo'
...
```

And I tried this, but no luck. It just replaces the version in my /api-docs, but UI ignores that and uses the spec-file's version instead.

src/main/kotlin/com/my/api/Application.kt

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class MyLittleApplication {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = ["springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled"], havingValue = "true")
    fun swaggerCustomization(buildProperties: BuildProperties): OpenApiCustomiser {
        return OpenApiCustomiser { openApi ->
            openApi.info.version(buildProperties.version)
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MyLittleApplication>(*args)
}
```